# Why does GC.GetTotalMemory() report huge memory allocations?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been playing around with GC.GetTotalMemory(). When I create a local variable of type Titles in the example below, the consumed amount of memory increases by 6276 bytes. What's going on here?

```
class Program
{
    enum Titles { Mr, Ms, Mrs, Dr };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetTotalMemory();
        Titles t = Titles.Dr;
        GetTotalMemory();
    }

    static void GetTotalMemory()
    {
        long bytes = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: 6KB seems like a strange definition of "huge"

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if `Console.WriteLine(...)` allocates memory.

Comment: 6KB is "huge" because what one expects is an increase of exactly 0 bytes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is because allocator somewhere bite a big piece of memory. It will use it for more than one object. Try to do:

```
GetTotalMemory();
Titles t = Titles.Dr;
GetTotalMemory();
Titles t2 = Titles.Mr;
GetTotalMemory();
```

and see what happens.

here is what i see, and GetTotalMemory() is not so innocent:

```
    GetTotalMemory();
    Titles t = Titles.Dr;            
    GetTotalMemory();
```

outputs:

```
12828
19484
```

and this:

```
GetTotalMemory();
//Titles t = Titles.Dr;            
GetTotalMemory();
```

outputs:

```
12828
19484
```

actually you should not pay attention to small fluctuations of free memory:

> Then saith he unto them, Render
>   therefore unto Caesar the things which
>   are Caesar's; and unto God the things
>   that are God's

:)